# how to get json data from wiki to display content of known page with page id

Tags: json, web-services, wiki, wikipedia

when I get return from this url;
http://tr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=Yavuz%20Bahad%C4%B1ro%C4%9Flu

returned content doesnt contain information in title (=Yavuz%20Bahad%C4%B1ro%C4%9Flu) but it contains page id to display actual information page relevant to title.


my actual demand is all information on this page;

http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yavuz_Bahad%C4%B1ro%C4%9Flu

How can I get json inf. from this page or with page id?

Comment: I had tried to realize wikipedia api but I couldnt overcome. I used like this http://tr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=Yavuz%20Bahad%C4%B1ro%C4%9Flu

Comment: Well perhaps you should open a question related to the specific problems you were having with the wikipedia API. As it stands now, there is really no specific question here to provide answer to.  You have been pointed in the right direction, you just need to try to work with the API.

Comment: Thanks I will change content of my question :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all information"? Do you want to get the text of the page as wikitext? Or as HTML? Or something else?

Comment: I want text actually. But all text of content not only page id like this page : http://tr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=Yavuz%20Bahad%C4%B1ro%C4%9Flu